# Convert SQL statement to Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-server-2008

I've got two tables, and I want to compare the data between them, and pick out the data from one table which is not present in the other. I already have a code that works in SQL Server Management, but I need to convert it into Rails or I need to be able to use raw SQL code in my code. Here is the code:

```
select * from app_servers
where not exists 
( select app, environment, server 
            from stagings
            where stagings.server = app_servers.server_id
            AND
            stagings.environment = app_servers.environment_id 
            AND 
            app_servers.app_id = stagings.app
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And do you have a model for App_Servers or you're starting from nothing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you want to convert it? You might use it as it is

```
AppServer.where(" not exists 
      ( select app, environment, server 
        from stagings
        where stagings.server = app_servers.server_id
        AND
        stagings.environment = app_servers.environment_id 
        AND 
        app_servers.app_id = stagings.app
      )
")
```

Comment: There's an argument to be made that you should always at least try to get your sql into AREL. This one makes my head spin a tiny bit because I don't know about models and possible associations here. I'm not saying don't do what you're suggesting, but I'd make a pass at using the ActiveRecord query syntax first. [guide to Arel](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: I agree with you Maybe there is not much benefit in this particular case but in general it's really handy. So see update.

Comment: @Bohdan Pohorilets nice, that worked for me ;-)
I'll try out the change without the `select * from app_servers` and let you know.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly you have two models, `AppServer` and `Staging` and both have an environment, server and an application.
You are looking for `AppServer`'s that do not have a corresponding `Staging`.

So your models would look like:

```
class AppServer
  belongs_to :server
  belongs_to :environment
  belongs_to :app
end

class Staging
  belongs_to :server
  belongs_to :environment
  belongs_to :app
end
```

But what you actually would want, is something like

```
class AppServer 
  belongs_to :server
  belongs_to :environment
  belongs_to :app
  has_one :staging
end
```

which would be really easy to test. Something like:

```
AppServer.where(:staging_id => nil)
```

So you could consider reforming your datamodel to make this easier.
This would not be too hard: add a single column, and for each app_server find the corresponding staging.

But suppose you do not have any control over your datamodel, you would need to write something like

```
class AppServer
  has_many :stagings, finder_sql => 'select * from stagings where server=#{server_id} and environment=#{environment_id} and app=#{app_id}'
```

Note: you must use single quotes!!
This would at least allow you to access something like

```
app_server = AppServer.first
app_server.stagings
```

Unfortunately, it does not allow you to write something like

```
AppServer.where(:stagings => nil)
```

To find all `AppServer` without staging, and you cant convert the schema, you will need to do something like

```
AppServer.where(" not exists 
  ( select app, environment, server 
    from stagings
    where stagings.server = app_servers.server_id
    AND
    stagings.environment = app_servers.environment_id 
    AND 
    app_servers.app_id = stagings.app
  )"
)
```

So actually, in the end, I did not find a new and improved way using arel.
But I did show some ways to allow making use of some rails helpers, and secondly it seems a good approach, if possible (even using views), to convert your datamodel to a more rails-friendly model. One good reason is that the rails way of creating data models is actually a pretty good way.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome dude. Thanks a lot for the help. Managed to get it up and running, through @Bohdan Pohorilets help, but regardless, I'll be sure to look at your answer and reuse it in the future ;-)